# New Text Editor issues with Mathjax

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Just wanted to bring this to everyone's attention. StackExchange is in the early stages of replacing the current text editor for questions/answers with a new one that supports rich-text. The problem with this, as mentioned in an [answer to the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360142#360142), is it could make it more cumbersome to write Mathjax (the main way we present equations on this site).

Over on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/the-proposed-changes-to-the-text-editor-would-break-this-site?cb=1), they have started brainstorming potential ways that the editor could be improved to better handle Mathjax, since it is used on so many sites in the network. Take a look at these posts and provide comments/votes to show this is important and to express what you would like to see in a new text editor.